# Can python coverage display results hierarchically?

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-coverage

I use the [Python code coverage tool](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) to monitor and measure our testing coverage.  I'm now publishing the results internally, using coverage's excellent html report generation.  I'd like to change the reports generated from a flat report of all modules to a nested/hierarchical approach, such that each module would display totals for the modules within.  Thus, if my current summary page looks like:

```
Name                         Stmts   Miss  Cover
myapp                           33     33     0%
myapp.infra                      2      0   100%
myapp.infra.mm                  34      8    76%
myapp.infra.mmcheck            140     32    77%
myapp.job                        2      2     0%
myapp.job.jobcontrol           629    445    29%
myapp.job.launcher             334    163    51%
```

I would instead like a summary report like:

```
Name                         Stmts   Miss  Cover
myapp.__init__                  33     33     0%
myapp.infra                    176     40    77%
myapp.job                      965    610    37%
```

Where myapp.infra links to an index for that package:

```
Name                         Stmts   Miss  Cover
myapp.infra.__init__             2      0   100%
myapp.infra.mm                  34      8    76%
myapp.infra.mmcheck            140     32    77%
```

Does a capability like this already exist, and I am simply too foolish to see it?  Or will I need to customize the report generation?

Comment: I ended up creating a custom subclass of the coverage's html.HtmlReporter.  My subclass recursively creates instances of itself during the overridden index_file method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [z3c.coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.coverage). Quote from docs:

> Why use z3c.coverage instead of coverage html?
>
> Some people prefer the look of the reports produced by z3c.coverage.
>   Some people find per-package coverage summaries or the tree-like
>   navigation convenient.

Sounds like what you need. Hope that helps.